# Debugging Typhoon Assemblies

Tags: typhoon

I've done refactoring in my project and suddenly Typhoon injections stop working. Looks like I missed something.

Is there any good way to debug object instantiation? In which Typhoon classes I should put breakpoints to find problem?

Comment: More info please. What kind of refactoring did you do? Is there an error message, or injection just stops working?

Comment: Injection just stop working. No error messages.

Comment: It was big refactoring. But it's not related to typhoon assemblies.
I just want to debug it and find problem

Comment: I've found the problem!

Comment: :) Can you post your solution - maybe helpful to others.

Comment: If you add localization to storyboard (main or launch screen) controller instantiation with typhoon stop working.

Comment: Wow, haven't heard of that before. Possible to post some sample code and/or open an issue on GH? This kind of issue will be given priority.

Comment: Sure. I'll try do it on weekend and post an issue to Typhoon repo